# Devise session does not persist on different URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, localhost

I have a rails application and I am using devise for authentication.
When I get logged in successfully on URL http://localhost:5000/,
I try to access http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the same browser.
I expect to be logged in as soon as I access it on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but application remains logged out. Whats going on I really cannot understand as I am trying to access both URLs in the same browser?

UPDATE:

my config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cache_store, key: '_app'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are logged in is store in the `session` which is stored in a `cookie`. For security reasons, the browser sends cookies only to the URLs from which the cookie was set.

From the browser's point of view, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are totally different URLs. Therefore the login information stored in the cookie on `localhost` is not sent to the server running at `127.0.0.1` and therefore the server running at `127.0.0.1` has no information about an existing session on `localhost`.

UPDATE:

Using the `cache_store` to store the session doesn't change anything because the information what session in the cache store belongs to the user is still stored in the cookie.

Imaging that your server needs to store all generated sessions somewhere. And if a user comes backs the server needs to know which session belongs to the user. A simplified solution to this problem might be to assign a random number to each session and give the user this number (stored in the cookie). When the user returns the cookie is returned too and that allows the server to load the session by that number.

And a cookie is bound to a domain. This is a security feature of the browser. If it didn't work that way all sessions would be sent to all domains: Google would know if you were logged in to Facebook, every website would know that you have a cookie from your bank...